# Validating numeric value in text field does not give desired result

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Validating a text field value which may be positive whole number or number with one decimal point and one decimal after the point in javascript:

```
123
1
12345
233.2
1212.2
1.1
```

are valid numbers and

```
1.222
1.33
-89789
-3
```

are invalid numbers.

Ihave applied this but not get desired result

```
  function CheckOneDecimal(txtbox) {
             if (txtbox.value.length > 0)
             {
                 if (isNaN(txtbox.value)) {
                     txtbox.value = "";
                     alert("Please enter number with one decimal places");
                     txtbox.focus();
                     return;
                 }
                 else if (parseFloat(txtbox.value) > 0)
                 {
                     txtbox.value = "";
                     alert("Please enter number with one decimal places. eg. 8.1");
                     txtbox.focus();
                     return;
                 }

                 var oRegExp = /^\s*\d+\.\d{1}\s*$/;
                   if (oRegExp.test(txtbox.value))
                     { }
                   else {

                         txtbox.value = "";
                         alert("Please enter number with one decimal places");
                         txtbox.focus();
                     }
               }
         }
```

Comment: "but not get desired result" - what *do* you get?

Comment: i just get the empty txtbox after validation. if txt have value 3.444 or 32323 it is only valid if it have 4.5.But it is working fine by below solution great thing thanks for replying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should do:

```
/^\d*\.?\d$/
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/ovaVAfU/1/edit

Comment: thaks for your great help. thank you very much.its working perfect

Comment: Can you tell me where i can learn this regex development. thanks

Comment: This will give `.2` as valid. I'm not sure it's wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d)?$/
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^\d+(?:\.\d)?$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```